# How to mimic PS Gradient Map effect with SVG feColorMatrix?

Tags: css, svg, photoshop

I've been struggling to understand **SVG feColorMatrix** equation.

I'm more home with Photoshop than SVG scripting. In Photoshop there is "**Gradient Map**" adjustment layer for applying your gradient to photo:

[image]

Some how I think that should be also achieved with SVG color matrix, but how?

Here's a simple [codepen](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/EaVvRZ) with svg filter above and desired Photoshop output below.

I have made this filter:

```
<filter id="colored">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"
    values="0.3334 0      0      0 0
            0      0.8196 0      0 0
            0      0      0.6471 0 0
            0      0      0      1 0 "/>
</filter>
```

.. but this does not do the job:

[image]

All hints welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think I came pretty close by combining two filters:

```
<filter id="colors">
  <feColorMatrix result="A" in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
    values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
            0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
            0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
            0      0      0      1 0 "/>
  </feColorMatrix>
  <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" in="A" type="matrix" 
    values="0.3334 0      0      0 0
            0      0.8196 0      0 0
            0      0      0.6471 0 0
            0      0      0      1 0 "/>         
  </feColorMatrix>
</filter>
```

[image]

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/GgpMRz)

Answer (score 1):

The example here is not working, but the code is explained:
http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/08/06/gradientmaps-js-gradient-maps-for-html/

Basically, what you seek is this:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="0" height="0">
    <filter id="filter-1438364318222">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="gray"></feColorMatrix>
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.3333333333333333"></feFuncR>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.8196078431372549"></feFuncG>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0.6470588235294118"></feFuncB>
            <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1"></feFuncA>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

0.3333 is 85/255 and so on...you get the idea...

Here is a codepen with the end result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzEXV